# Server-side validation with custom messages in Vee-validate v3

Tags: nuxt.js, vee-validate, vue-i18n

In my Nuxt app, I use Vee-validate v3 together with Vue-i18n. I understand that it will validate using the `vid` and display the error using the `setErrors` function but in my case, the response from the server where like these `validation.required`, `validation.unique` and so on. What I would like to achieve is to display a custom error message based from a rule that matches from my custom `lang.js` file.

I tried to use the configure and supply messages to the defaultMessages but not working.

**i18n.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from '../utils/lang'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

console.log(messages) 
// { en: { validation: (...) }}

export default ({ app }) => {
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages: messages,
  })
}
```

**validator.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { required, email } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
import {
  ValidationProvider,
  ValidationObserver,
  extend,
  configure,
} from 'vee-validate'

export default ({ app }) => {
  configure({
    defaultMessage: (_, values) =>
      app.i18n.t(`validations.validation.${values._rule_}`, values),
  })
}

// Add rules
extend('required', {
  ...required,
  message: `{_field_} is required`,
})

extend('email', {
  ...email,
  message: 'Please fill in a valid email address',
})

// Global components
Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver)
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)
```

Answer (score 2):

`defaultMessage` of `vee-validate.configure()` only works when there is no specific message set by rules, as noted by [VeeValidate official document](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/configuration.html#reference).

> *defaultMessage*: The fallback message for rules without messages.

There's custom error messages in your Vee validate configuration prevents fallback error message function from working. Removing them from Vee-validate rules and putting them on i18n messages seems to work.

```js
// validator.js
extend('required', {
  ...required,
  // remove the message
})

extend('email', {
  ...email,
  // remove the message
})

// i18n.js
export default ({ app }) => {
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages: {
      // put the messages here instead, with keys given from `configure().defaultMessage`
      validations: {
        validation: {
          required: `{_field_} is required`,
          email: 'Please fill in a valid email address'
        }
      }
    },
  })
}
```

Here's [working code on github](https://github.com/rabelais88/stackoverflow-answers/tree/main/74150854-vee-validate3)(vee-validate v3 + nuxt-i18n + nuxt)